# Як перекласти з російської "новодел"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian, одним-словом

Є одну досить влучне слово *новодел*. Означає воно сучасний виріб, виконаний у стилі «під старовину». Виріб може бути, архітектурний, художній, музичний, дизайновий тощо.

Наприклад, [оцей музичний твір](https://bytebuster.dreamwidth.org/9975972.html) 2012 року, що виконаний у стилі італо-диско 1980-х років. Як бачимо, блогер використав суржикове слово *новодєл*. Таке зловживання суржиком можна вважати допустимим у персональному блозі, але не в більш офіційному контексті.

Є ще слово [*новотвір*](http://sum.in.ua/s/novotvir). Воно має сенс щодо *сучасного*, але не несе конотації, що це підробка під старовину.

**Чи є краще слово**, яке б не мало названого недоліку?

Comment: Гадаю, родич-запитання: [Чи має термін **креативність** синоніми українського походження?](/q/4079/585)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**Новотві́р**](http://sum.in.ua/s/novotvir), **вору,** *чол.* Форма, елемент, слово і т. ін., що утворилися заново.

Коли брати опис СУМ‑11, то тут хитре слово „заново“, що може нести „старе“.

> [**За́ново**](http://sum.in.ua/s/zanovo), *присл.*, *розм.*
>
> 1. Знову, ще раз.
> 2. По-новому; не так, як раніше.
> 3. Нещодавно, щойно.

Але воно й на те і хитре, бо має розбіжні означення, ще цікавіше — чомусь для опису вжили  слово з міткою „розмовне“. Але загалом так, не несе суто означення „підробки“.

Коли поглянути на основу слова „новодел“, то воно складається з „новое“ і „делать“. Очевидно, що для другого слова українська вживає „робити“. Схоже таким чином міркували творці [російсько-українського народного сучасного словника 2009](//r2u.org.ua/html/announcement.html):

> [Новодел](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB&scope=all&dicts=10&highlight=on) – **новоро́бка**:
>
> • *делающий новоделы* – новороб. *Всі слова на* ‑роб *стосуються людських професій, рис:* не́роб (неро́ба), хліборо́б, виноро́б, доморо́б, карторо́б, дзиґоро́б *тощо*, «новоробка» *ж із ряду* «обро́бка», «ви́робка», «доро́бка», «підро́бка».

Здавалося, що все зроблено-пороблено, та й слово поготів [вживається](//google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0&lr=-lang_ru&safe=off), щоправда, також і як [новороб](//google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1&lr=-lang_ru&safe=off) з означенням предмета.

Але моє серце [крається](http://www.ji.lviv.ua/n35texts/kocherha.htm). Тобто українська закінчення *‑ка* цілком [має](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky), не заперечую, [але](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine62-20.pdf) ж… Як щодо *‑ріб*? Тобто *обріб*, [*виріб*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyrib), [*дорібок*](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/13467-doribok.html), *підріб*? А отже і **новоріб**.